# How do you encode a string within the MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, encode

I've tried using this:

```
Forum.Body = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Forum.Body);
```

To encode the a string of text but it still doesn't encode the variable. What's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Razor automatically HTML encodes by default as a security measure.

If you pass a `Forum` model object to the view and use razor all you will have to do is this:

```
@Model.Body
```

In the above it will encode the `Body` property by default.

This means that you shouldn't have to HTML encode from within the controller.

**update**

If you intend to output html you can either use:

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.Body)
```

Or add the following attribute to the property:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Comment: For bonus points show @Html.Raw() usage, as I have an idea this is what the op might really want. Also consider HtmlString or whatever that class is that is handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks, good points. I have updated it. I will add HtmlString explanation when I get to a PC. @timothywalters